# Linq RemoveFirst equivalent

Tags: linq, lambda, ienumerable

I was looking for a Linq `RemoveFirst(Predicate<T> match)` but could only find `RemoveAll`.

I know I can write my own extension method but was wondering if there already exists an equivalent function with a different name, or an easy way to achieve the same result.

Comment: That's not LINQ; it's been there since .Net 2.0.

Comment: `RemoveAll` is an instance method on `List<T>`. It is not part of LINQ.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `IEnumerable<T>`, which is a read-only interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
list.RemoveAt(list.FindIndex(x => thingy));
```

If no item is found, an exception will be thrown.

Note that this has nothing to do with LINQ and can only be done with `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not actually "remove" the element from the sequence since, as @SLaks points out linq sequences are readonly, but it does skip the first occurrence of the element that meets the criteria.  It is not particularly efficient as each list operation is going to iterate over the list.  It is reasonably expressive of what you are trying to accomplish.  Depending on how many items you expect to have in your list, this might be reasonable for you.

```
  IEnumerable<int> x = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);
  var y = x.TakeWhile(xx => xx < 10).Concat(x.SkipWhile(xx => xx < 10).Skip(1));

  //Will write 0 1 2 ... 19, skipping 10
  foreach(int a in y)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has provided one, here's my extension method/enumerable that implements RemoveFirst(Predicate match). The trick is basically that you need to define your own IEnumerable to track the state properly--I couldn't find an easy way around that.

You can try it out in a [.NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5U7QsP).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return new RemoveFirstEnumerable<T>(list, predicate);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T item)
{
    return RemoveFirst(list, x => Object.Equals(x, item));
}
private class RemoveFirstEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> m_Source;
    Func<T, bool> m_Predicate;

    public RemoveFirstEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        m_Source = source;
        m_Predicate = predicate;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new RemoveFirstEnumerator(m_Source, m_Predicate);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new RemoveFirstEnumerator(m_Source, m_Predicate);
    }

    private class RemoveFirstEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        IEnumerator<T> m_Enumerator;
        Func<T, bool> m_Predicate;
        bool m_RemovedOnce = false;
        public RemoveFirstEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            m_Enumerator = source.Where(WherePredicate).GetEnumerator();
            m_Predicate = predicate;
        }

        bool WherePredicate(T current)
        {
            // terse version:
            return m_RemovedOnce || !(m_RemovedOnce = m_Predicate(current));

            // Long version
            //if (m_RemovedOnce)
            //{
            //    return true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    m_RemovedOnce = Object.Equals(x, item);
            //    return !m_RemovedOnce;
            //}
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return m_Enumerator.Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return m_Enumerator.MoveNext();
        }


        public void Reset()
        {
            m_Enumerator.Reset();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_Enumerator.Dispose();
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return m_Enumerator.Current; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the classic List has a RemoveAll(match) but not a RemoveFirst(match). An extension method could be

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveFirst<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(list.FindIndex(match));
    }
}
```